# Copy iframe content to another iframe without jquery, prevents network use

Tags: angular

I have 2 iframes and I'm trying to copy the content from iframe to another iframe and prevents network use to download the same content again.

So it´s an angular2 code:

```
<div *ngFor="let url of urls; let i=index">

    <iframe [src]={{url}}></iframe>

    <div class="modal-iframe">
                <iframe [src]={{url}}></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

The second iframe is a thumbnail, can I copy content without jquery?

Answer (score -1):

You can never really prevent people from downloading your images, once they're transferred to their browser, especially not by just putting them inside an iframe - I would advise you to work with some kind of watermark like Shutterstock does and just display them as regular images :)